# How to change the cache in bind9?

Tags: dns, bind

Now I have a RR in cache but I want to change it. Like this, I have `xx.yy IN A 1.1.1.1` in cache and now I want to change it to `xx.yy IN A 2.2.2.2`. Is there any built-in tools of `bind9`?(no-restart is better)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`rndc flush` flushes the server's cache. You cannot go and edit what is already there. If this is a local zone, freeze it, edit it and increase the serial number, thaw it, then issue `rndc reload [zone]`.